# Could not resolve hostname: when pushing to Github private repo from a CircleCI job

Tags: git, github, circleci-2.0

I am working on Github-CircleCI integration. One of my job wants to push a git tag to the same repository. But everytime I try to do so, I get the following error:

```
    ssh: Could not resolve hostname : Name or service not known

    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
    and the repository exists.
```

I followed the steps as mentioned in the docs https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/gh-bb-integration/#creating-a-github-deploy-key. But that doesn't work. I made sure I have write access to my new deploy key. I also added fingerprint to my yml file.

```
version: 2.0
jobs:
  deploy:
    steps:
      - add_ssh_keys:
          fingerprints:
            - "<FINGERPRINT>"
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: deploy
          command: |
                  git tag -a v1.0.0 -m "test tag"
                  echo "tag created"
                  git push origin v1.0.0
                  echo "tag pushed"

workflows:
  version: 2
  build-and-deploy:
    jobs:
      - deploy:
          filters:
             branches:
              only:
                - /^test/
```

I get the tag created successfully. But it errors out with the above mentioned error whenever it tries to push the tag.

Can anyone point the missing thing? Any help appreciated!

Comment: Your remote `origin` doesn't seem to be configured correctly, missing a hostname?

Comment: @vlumi I have added an SSH key in CircleCI with hostname as `github.com`. Even if the hostname is not specified, it should be used for all hosts!

Comment: Are you building behind a proxy?

Comment: @masseyb No, no proxy set!

Comment: It doesn't look like it even got to the stage where it would check your SSH key; the configuration of the git origin seems to be lacking. Check your `.git/config`.

Comment: @vlumi Doesn't SSH key means giving access to the particular repo rather than configuring git with username or token or something?

Comment: @amal The key is used for authentication (in place of a password), which is done after connecting to the server. The connection itself appears to be failing, as the hostname is empty -- likely due to mis-configuration.